# Task Scheduler failing to Kill Outlook

Tags: outlook, task, kill

I have a scheduled task to kill outlook and this task runs with SYSTEM account (Run whenever user is logged or not / Run with highest privileges are marked)

The action is:

```
- Start a program
- Program/Script: "taskkill/im outlook.exe"
```

This doesn't work neither with "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe taskkill/im outlook.exe"

I get the error:

```
Task Scheduler failed to start instance "{a394e482-f326-47ad-995e-664f484926e9}" of
"\Close Outlook"  task for user "DOMAIN\CA18-0JG5S49$". 
Additional Data: Error Value: 2147942403
```

Any ideas on what to do?

I **DO NOT** want to use VBS to kill Outlook. It must be done directly with a command.

Thanks.

Comment: C:\Users\David Candy>net helpmsg 3

The system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a space between `taskkill` and its arguments. Change

```
taskkill/im outlook.exe
```

into

```
taskkill /im outlook.exe
```

Basically, `taskkill` should be in the "Program" field of the task, and `/im outlook.exe` in the "Arguments" field.

Comment: I did as you said and I don't get the error anymore but Outlook is not closed and remains opened.   Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\Close Outlook" , instance "{19abd392-3796-4cc8-996d-6fd5e0c7e120}" , action "C:\WINDOWS\system32\taskkill.EXE" with return code 1.

Comment: Change the program to `cmd.exe` and the arguments to `/c taskkill /im outlook.exe >C:\out.txt 2>&1`. What does `C:\out.txt` say after you ran the task?

Comment: I changed the program to cmd.exe and the arguments to /c taskkill /im outlook.exe >C:\out.txt

The out.txt is blank

Comment: I am getting `Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\Close Outlook" , instance "{27be537c-2ba2-436e-9f04-6ba06eff0e0d}" , action "cmd.exe" with return code 1.` from the task Scheduler

Comment: I also changed the program to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` but I get the same results

Comment: I am also trying to use PowerShell to do it but it doesnt work `Get-Process | Where { $_.Name -Eq "outlook" } | stop-process` The command alone in PowerShell works as well.

Comment: Get rid of cmd as it's not needed and makes things more complex. Just do taskkill /im "outlook.exe". The command you are using is the same as clicking the close button, Outlook is free to ignore it and will if there is unsaved data like a 1/2 composed email. Use the /f option. Also lets dump the task info to look at schtasks /query /tn alarm2 /v /fo list. Use runas to run the command under the  username the task is scheduled as to see what taskkill is saying runas /noprofile /user:serenity\administrator "taskkill /im \"outlook.exe\" /f"

Comment: @DavidCandy `cmd` is required for output redirection to work (in order to check if the command generates any helpful output). Which was the purpose of this exercise.

Comment: I understood why you wanted it in but it generated no output so needs to be removed to simplify the issue. It is a bit of a worry that it didn't work. Now the VBS to VB question was answered a while ago. Thanks for making me look at 100 pages.

Comment: I kept cmd.exe and Under arguments runas /noprofile /user:CA18-0JG5S49\SYSTEM "taskkill /im \"outlook.exe\" /f" but nothing happens. @David, is this correct? There is no unsaved data and I will not be able to run as administrator. I have other tasks running under SYSTEM just fine.

Comment: When running the command manually runas /noprofile /user:CA18-0JG5S49\SYSTEM "taskkill /im \"outlook.exe\" /f" I get prompted for a password and this will not work either. I cannot inform any passwords and this should run without the need to inform any passwords

Comment: I am also seeing Task Scheduler failed to start "\Close Outlook" task for user "NT AUTHORITY\System". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147750687.

Comment: @rogernem Do not use `runas` in scheduled tasks. If you need to run a task under a different account, specify that account in the task properties. Also, there is no user `HOSTNAME\SYSTEM`. `SYSTEM` is a built-in security principal, and the correct (full) name is `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`. However, you shouldn't be running scheduled tasks under that account anymore (not since Windows Vista). For what you're trying to achieve I'd use a dedicated admin account.

Comment: From winerror.h for 8004131f (use calc to conmvert the number to hex). //
// MessageId: SCHED_E_ALREADY_RUNNING
//
// MessageText:
//
// An instance of this task is already running.
//
#define SCHED_E_ALREADY_RUNNING          _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x8004131FL)
So your task is already running. PS You can't use Runas to run as system. Try with localsystem account in TS and see if it chanhges.

Comment: The problem to run with the admin account is that I cannot store passwords due to global network policy. Tasks run as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. The tasks were created with the admin account.

Comment: @rogernem You don't need to, since you don't want to access network resources. Simply check the "don't save the password" box, and the password won't be saved, although you'll still have to provide it for task creation.

Comment: I shouldn't need to use the admin account for this task and even when I do that it doesn't work.

Comment: We want you to run it as admin for testing purposes, so we can see the output of the command. As your task is running, so you can't run it again, lets see what we can about it. 1. "C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\New Folder\PsTools\PsExec.exe" C:\Users\David Candy>"C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\New Folder\PsTools\PsExec.exe" -s cmd /c taskkill /im winword.exe /f - this kills winword as system account 2. Lets dump the command line of running programs - wmic process get commandline. 3. Lets use schtasks to run it schtasks /run /tn <Taskname>

Comment: As I said before, running as admin doesnt change the result. It simply will not close outlook. I will try that and see if there is any output

Comment: Can you please provide exactly what I need to configure as what you described is confusing? 1. "C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\New Folder\PsTools\PsExec.exe" C:\Users\David Candy>"C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\New Folder\PsTools\PsExec.exe" -s cmd /c taskkill /im winword.exe /f - this kills winword as system account 2. Lets dump the command line of running programs - wmic process get commandline. 3. Lets use schtasks to run it schtasks /run /tn <Taskname>

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but throwing in something no-one else seems to have mentioned.

Using `taskkill /T /im outlook.exe` doesn't work the FIRST time, but if you run this command with say 2 emails opened and the reminders box, it will close the reminders box. Run it again, and closes outlook. Sometimes, you have to run it a third time, as it only closes emails on the second attempt, but 3 times is a charm, usually.

Not very consistent, but at a push, you could put the command into the batch file 3 times to give clunky but workable outlook shutdown routine. I've seen similar behaviour with other commands. For instance, `rmdir /S` doesn't always delete the full directory structure on the first attempt, so when using it in a batch file I would always put it in twice to be sure, to be sure.

Comment: just add your thoughts as a comment, is it really a new answer?